# Why am I getting the following error in Python "ImportError: No module named py"?

Tags: python

I'm a Python newbie, so bear with me :)

I created a file called test.py with the contents as follows:

```
test.py
import sys
print sys.platform
print 2 ** 100
```

I then ran `import test.py` file in the interpreter to follow an example in my book.
When I do this, I get the output with the import error on the end.

```
win32
1267650600228229401496703205376
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named py
```

Why do I get this error and how do I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Instead of:

```
import test.py
```

simply write:

```
import test
```

This assumes test.py is in the same directory as the file that imports it.

Answer (score 8):

This strange-looking error is a result of how Python imports modules.

**Python sees**:

```
import test.py
```

**Python thinks** (simplified a bit):

> import module test.
>
> - search for a test.py in the module search paths
> - execute test.py (where you get your output)
> - import 'test' as name into current namespace
>
> import test.py
>
> - search for file test/py.py
> - throw ImportError (no module named 'py') found.

Because python allows dotted module names, it just thinks you have a submodule named `py` within the `test` module, and tried to find that.  It has no idea you're attempting to import a file.

Comment: I think the terminology is technically "*module* named `py` within the `test` *package*". (Could be wrong, though!)

Answer (score 6):

You don't specify the extension when importing. Just do:

```
import test
```

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, you don't need to put the file extension in your import statement. Recommended reading is the [Modules section of the Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html).

For a little more background into the error, the interpreter thinks you're trying to import a module named `py` from inside the `test` package, since the dot indicates encapsulation. Because no such module exists (and [test isn't even a package](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages)!), it raises that error.

As indicated in the [more in-depth documentation on the import statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement) it still executes all the statements in the `test` module before attempting to import the `py` module, which is why you get the values printed out.